# Accessing a field specified as <field name="TheName"> using "TheName" using lxml

Tags: python, xml, lxml

Is it possible to access the  in the following example data using the "TheName" designation? 
I'm relatively new to lxml and xml in general, this type of field strikes me as unusual.
Sadly, this is the output I have to work with.

Note that the number of children changes for each  field, so using the position of the "Name1" field doesn't work.

Example XML:

```
<main>
      <header>
        <row type="info">
          <field name="description"><![CDATA[Results]]></field>
          <field name="created"><![CDATA[6/12/2014 6:45:00 PM]]></field>
        </row>
        <row>
          <field name="profile"><![CDATA[Intel]]></field>
        </row>
      </header>
      <sections>
        <section name="Results">
          <description />
          <parameters />
          <header />
          <content>
            <row>
              # A row-dependend number of fields exist before the Full Content field
              <field name="Name1"><![CDATA[ I am the text of interest]]></field>
              <field name="AnotherName"><![CDATA[ There is content in this field, too]]></field>
              # A row-dependend number of fields follow here
            </row>
            # There are 40,000 of these row elements
          </content>
          <footer>
            <row type="content_count">
              <field name="count"><![CDATA[9981]]></field>
            </row>
          </footer>
        </section>
      </sections>
    </main>
```

So, how to get at the content of these  fields reliably?

Thank you for you considerations,
Matthias

Comment: What is "the "TheName" designation" ?

Comment: XPath is the standard, canonical way to access elements in XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access the `field` tag where `name="TheName"`, then use the following XPath: `/main/sections/section/content/row/field[@name='TheName']`

For more info, see http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp